# How to organize correctly Win32 message handling with DirectX?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm currently trying to develop a small rendering engine based on DirectX and the Win32 API. The problem I'm currently trying to solve is how to organize my code correctly to handle Windows messages that impact on DirectX code (for example, a WM_SIZE message, that implies resizing DirectX buffers).

It needs to be done in the WndProc function that is passed to the window when it's created, but I don't know how I can "transfer" the message I'm interested in. So far, I've only found this way:

```
//main.cpp
Renderer* renderer;

//some code 

//The window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    //We forward the message to the Renderer, which handles it or not
    if(renderer->HandleMessage(hWnd,message,wParam,lParam){
        return 0;
    }

    //If the renderer does not handle the message, we do as usual
    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that it relies on a global variable (renderer), which I don't feel comfortable with since I hear a lot that using global variables isn't good practice (and I feel I'm not experienced enough to decide if it's a case where I should use it)

I would like to know if there's a better approach to "forward" window messages without the need for a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, WM_PAINT is for GDI painting, not Direct3D rendering. Typically D3D apps render frames whenever possible.

Secondly, use `SetWindowLongPtr` to set a pointer to the renderer to an internal Windows variable associated with the HWND, which you can get back with `GetWindowLongPtr`.

Thirdly, you really should have a Window class wrapping this, which then chooses to tell the renderer about it, rather than directly interacting.

Edit: Here's the normal super-simple structure:

```
class Window {
    HWND hwnd;
    static ... WindowProc(...) {
        if (auto p = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA))
            return reinterpret_cast<Window*>(p)->ProcessMessage(...);
        else return DefWindowProc(...);
    }
    ... ProcessMessage(...) {
        /* whatever you want */
        if (msg == WM_RESIZE)
            OnResize(...);
    }
public:
    Window() {
        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));
    }
    std::function<void(unsigned, unsigned)> OnResize;
};
```

In this case ProcessMessage() is a member, and the Window just provides a callback which allows any external code to hook into this specific event.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I looked into the `SetWindowLongPtr`and `GetWindowLongPtr`. If I get it right, I should use `SetWindowLongPtr` to store a pointer to my Renderer in the `GWLP_USERDATA` attribute, and then use the getter, cast the returned value as a pointer to a Renderer, and call the appropriate member function(s) ? Anyway, I don't really understand how I can wrap this in a Window class, as I'll still need to provide a non-member function to `lpfnWndProc` in the WNDCLASSEX structure...

Comment: @JBL: Yes, that's right. You provide a non-member as the WNDPROC, but use the GWLP_USERDATA pointer slot to store a class pointer, which you promptly call a member function on.